# Heroku paperclip strange log. Then H12 Timeout Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I'm getting strange `[paperclip] Saving attachments.` log on each page. I could not reproduce it in my local.

Then, I am getting H12 Timeout Error on heroku 50%. I am not sure but I think it caused by the paperclip thing,

I have two questions:

1- How can I debug `[paperclip] Saving attachments.` log when and where is it running?

2- How can I monitor all actions and how long it takes on heroku?

Thank you so much?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are exceeding the 30 seconds limit? Heroku dynos will timeout after that time..

Comment: Yes, I'm exceeding 30 seconds limit. But, It is not so possible because It is very simple pages. There is only one strange log in production (not in development) `[paperclip] Saving attachments.` I think it caused by this. SO I want to debug.

Comment: Well, consider that the upload process is considered a request, so if your uploads are taking more than 30 seconds, the dynos will timeout and kill the process.

Comment: But, Although I upload anything I am getting paperclip log. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip logs `[paperclip] Saving attachments.` even when you do not change the image after updating the model.

I downloaded sample http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip_demo app. And see the log there.